# The requested URL returned 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems in a project asp.net mvc razor using kendo-grid. Data Model is as following:

```
public partial class Usuario
{
    private string _id;
    public virtual string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id;
        }
        set
        {
            this._id = value;
        }
    }

    private string _idPerfil;
    public virtual string IdPerfil
    {
        get
        {
            return this._idPerfil;
        }
        set
        {
            this._idPerfil = value;
        }
    }

    private string _idEntidad;
    public virtual string IdEntidad
    {
        get
        {
            return this._idEntidad;
        }
        set
        {
            this._idEntidad = value;
        }
    }

    private int? _idDepArea;
    public virtual int? IdDepArea
    {
        get
        {
            return this._idDepArea;
        }
        set
        {
            this._idDepArea = value;
        }
    }

    private Char _forzarCambioClave;
    public virtual Char ForzarCambioClave
    {
        get
        {
            return this._forzarCambioClave;
        }
        set
        {
            this._forzarCambioClave = value;
        }
    }

    private short? _idDirectivaSeguridad;
    public virtual short? IdDirectivaSeguridad
    {
        get
        {
            return this._idDirectivaSeguridad;
        }
        set
        {
            this._idDirectivaSeguridad = value;
        }
    }

    private string _hash;
    public virtual string Hash
    {
        get
        {
            return this._hash;
        }
        set
        {
            this._hash = value;
        }
    }

    private Char _requiereRol;
    public virtual Char RequiereRol
    {
        get
        {
            return this._requiereRol;
        }
        set
        {
            this._requiereRol = value;
        }
    }

    private string _idEstado;
    public virtual string IdEstado
    {
        get
        {
            return this._idEstado;
        }
        set
        {
            this._idEstado = value;
        }
    }

    private long _idPersona;
    public virtual long IdPersona
    {
        get
        {
            return this._idPersona;
        }
        set
        {
            this._idPersona = value;
        }
    }

    private Estado _estado;
    public virtual Estado Estado
    {
        get
        {
            return this._estado;
        }
        set
        {
            this._estado = value;
        }
    }

    private DirectivaSeguridad _directivaSeguridad;
    public virtual DirectivaSeguridad DirectivaSeguridad
    {
        get
        {
            return this._directivaSeguridad;
        }
        set
        {
            this._directivaSeguridad = value;
        }
    }

    private Entidad _entidade;
    public virtual Entidad Entidad
    {
        get
        {
            return this._entidade;
        }
        set
        {
            this._entidade = value;
        }
    }

    private Persona _persona;
    public virtual Persona Persona
    {
        get
        {
            return this._persona;
        }
        set
        {
            this._persona = value;
        }
    }

    private IList<Rol> _roles = new List<Rol>();
    public virtual IList<Rol> Roles
    {
        get
        {
            return this._roles;
        }
    }

    private IList<LogMasterAuditoria> _logsMasterAuditoria = new List<LogMasterAuditoria>();
    public virtual IList<LogMasterAuditoria> LogsMasterAuditoria
    {
        get
        {
            return this._logsMasterAuditoria;
        }
    }

}
```

Controller managing model is:

```
public class UsuariosController : BaseController
{
    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

    public ActionResult Cargar([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(backend.Usuarios.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

...
}

View is:

```html
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<NetInfinity.BackendCore.Usuario>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Filterable(false).Width(100).Title(@Usuarios.Id);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Persona.Nombres).Width(80).Title(@Usuarios.Nombre);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Estado.Descripcion).Width(60).Title(@Usuarios.NombrePerfil);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Persona.TipoIdentidad.FormatoPresentacion).Width(20).Title(@Usuarios.IdTipo);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Persona.NumeroIdentificacion).Width(30).Title(@Usuarios.IdNumero);
            columns.Command(c => c.Custom("Edit").Text("Editar"));
            columns.Command(c => c.Custom("Remove").Text("Eliminar"));
        })
        .ToolBar(t => { t.Excel(); })
        .Navigatable()
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Filterable()
        .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.Id))
            .Read(read => read.Action("Cargar", "Usuarios"))
         )
    )
</div>
```

Problem it seems raises when Json serialization from Controller is executed because no data is shown into the grid and table has rows. Maybe there is a problem serializing objects from model like virtual properties, eg: virtual  Persona object and others. Please need help on how to put it work.

Comment: 500 means something went wrong server side, can you have exception message and stack trace sent in response (ActionResult), or just debug it on server side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to debug it and get exception message + stack trace to detect the error? Debugger is a good tool to avoid "maybe". Moreover, ASP.NET should definitely return error description if such config has been turned on in Web.config.

Please, find the error by debugging and post the exception details here.

Or change your `Web.config` such that you have the following value:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Refresh the page and you will get your error's description.
Detect the error and fix it or post it here and we will help you.

Comment: Error is no happening in ASP.NET C# code, is a combination of kendo-grid and jquery errors. Errors is: POST http://localhost:3780/Soporte/Usuarios/Cargar 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-2.1.3.js:8625
send jquery-2.1.3.js:8625
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-2.1.3.js:8161
pt.extend.read kendo.web.min.js:11
m.transports.aspnetmvc-ajax.f.data.RemoteTransport.extend.read kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js:9
(anonymous function) kendo.web.min.js:11
ht.extend._queueRequest kendo.web.min.js:11
 ... continued

Comment: continue ... ht.extend.read kendo.web.min.js:11
ht.extend.query kendo.web.min.js:11
ht.extend._query kendo.web.min.js:11
ht.extend.fetch kendo.web.min.js:11
pt.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend.init kendo.web.min.js:30
(anonymous function) kendo.web.min.js:10
jQuery.extend.each jquery-2.1.3.js:374
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery-2.1.3.js:139
e.fn.(anonymous function) kendo.web.min.js:10
(anonymous function) VM375:1
fire jquery-2.1.3.js:3094
self.add jquery-2.1.3.js:3140
jQuery.fn.ready jquery-2.1.3.js:3373
jQuery.fn.init jquery-2.1.3.js:2816
jQuery jquery-2.1.3.js:76
(anonymous function) VM375:1
continue

Comment: continue ... jQuery.extend.globalEval jquery-2.1.3.js:328
jQuery.fn.extend.domManip jquery-2.1.3.js:5430
jQuery.fn.extend.append jquery-2.1.3.js:5213
(anonymous function) kendo.web.min.js:41
jQuery.extend.each jquery-2.1.3.js:374
h.extend.append kendo.web.min.js:41
$.ajax.success Principal:121
fire jquery-2.1.3.js:3094
self.fireWith jquery-2.1.3.js:3206
done jquery-2.1.3.js:8259
(anonymous function) jquery-2.1.3.js:8600. I had to split error into 3 comments

Comment: when kendo-grid executes .Read(read => read.Action("Cargar", "Usuarios")), it goes to controller executing return Json(backend.Usuarios.ToDataSourceResult(request)). Just when Json go back to kendo-grid, 500 internal server error is thrown. Problems is caused by complex object represented by Usuario class (having another class and Lists) because trying with a plain ViewModel of Usuario (Just simple properties), kendo-grid works fine. ¿will I have to change my project into a web-api?

Comment: Hello, by using fiddler I found this in the inspector: Error de servidor en la aplicación. Se detect&#243; una referencia circular al serializar un objeto de tipo 'NetInfinity.BackendCore.Usuario'. Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código. Detalles de la excepción: in System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, ...), in System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)